# Fedora reinstall keep files

Tags: linux, fedora, reinstall

Can I just copy over my home directory to a USB and copy them  back? Will this cause any problems with permissions or anything?

What about the option to install without wiping my home...will that work?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, that should work fine.

However, if your `/home` on its own partition, there is an easier way; the Fedora installer (called Anaconda) can be told to re-use the old `/home` partition as the new `/home` partition.

Answer (score 0):

If you backup and restore your `/home` directory there shouldn't be any major problems especially if you're reinstalling the same version of Fedora. Otherwise there might be a couple of SELinux issues caused by the fact that new labels must be used for some of the files, but it's highly unlikely.